# How Mongodb zones and shards relates to each other

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the document:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/

As the document states: "Zones cannot share ranges, nor can they have overlapping ranges."

But still, in the example: "Shards Alpha and Beta have the A zone. Shard Beta also has the B zone"

As I understand, A zone and B zone are sharing (or overlapping) shard Alpha. Why doesn't it conflict with the mentioned rule?

Answer (score 2):

"Overlapping ranges" refers to shard keys. E.g. in the example given, zone A covers keys [1, 10) and zone B covers keys [10, 20). An example of overlap would be zone B covering keys [5, 20).

There is no *requirement* that a shard only contains  chunks belonging to one zone. The documentation says (emphasis mine):

> You **can** associate each zone with one or more shards in the cluster.

Such an association is optional.

Answer (score 1):

yes the documentation is little confusing.

I will try to explain with an example.

**Stage 1**

Let's say you are managing a school. And you have several students with different subjects. You have sharded setup with 5 shards. Initially data would be distributed among all of them equally.

But let's say students are not located at the same studying facility. But geographically located on different part of globe. Now the current sharding does not provide best experience for all of them. Hence we may want to colocate data for them near their study center.

**Stage 2**

Hence we bring up another mongodb instances near study center. And assign zone to those instances. You can assign multiple zone to same shard as well.

No rebalancing has happened yet, we have just assigned zones to shards.

**Stage 3**

In this step we will assign `Maths min-max keys` (means all maths document) to `ZONE_Maths` (and similarly for other subjects).  Once we enabled rebalancing the Step 1 will move to step3. And data would be assign as you have asked.

[image]

Now revisiting what has been written in the documentation

> You can associate each zone with one or more shards in the cluster.`

Example: ZONE_Maths, ZONE_Physics are distributed on more than 1 shard.

> A shard can associate with any number of zones.

Example: Stard4 has data for multiple zones.

> In a balanced cluster, MongoDB migrates chunks covered by a zone only to those shards associated with the zone

Once the balancing is completed, the cluster will reach in state as you defined.

> Zones cannot share ranges, nor can they have overlapping ranges.

Zones have to be mutually exclusive. Otherwise Mongo will not be able to decide where to put the data.

**NOTE the stage1's shard 1 has nothing to do with stage3's shard 1. Once we understand this, it makes things more clear.**

Refer to this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/) Once you see my explanation, I hope it will clear things.